# How to make ImageField returns relative path?

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, imagefield

I don't know why, but my ImageFields return full URL pathes.

This is MEDIA_URL setting:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/cc/cc/media/'
```

I use this custom FileStorage:

```
class ASCIIFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        return str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + name.split('.')[-1]
```

And simple ModelSerializers (from django rest framework) without overwriting smth like that for model Module1Item:

```
class Module1Item(models.Model):
    ...
    background = models.ImageField(blank=True)


class Module1ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Module1Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

What can be the reason of those behaviour? I need relative URLs.

Comment: Can you add your serializer and `MEDIA_URL` setting value?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, ok, I have added them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

serializer's `ImageField` using absulute url by default. You can override `to_representation` method to change it:

```
class Module1ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Module1Item
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super(Module1ItemSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        if instance.background:
            response['background'] = instance.background.url
        return response
```

Comment: why not `source`?

Comment: @BearBrown oops, totally forgot about it:(

Comment: @BearBrown Just wonder will `source='background.url'` raise has no file associated with it if background is empty?

Comment: @BearBrown By the way, I tried background = serializers.ImageField(source='background.url') and it returns null although it returns value with relative path when I overrided to_representation. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler you need change `serializers.ImageField` to `serializers.CharField` if you want use `source`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with example from the comments above.

```
class Module1ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    background = serializers.CharField(source="background.url")
    class Meta:
        model = Module1Item
        fields = '__all__'
```